# How to modify an inherited list in the __init__ method of a subclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, init

Is it possible to change something in the **init** function of a class?

Lets say I have a class called "deck" which, when initialized, creates a list of 52 card objects.

Now I want to make another class called "even" which inherits from "deck" class and creates a deck of card objects BUT eliminates all cards with a number 2 (so spades, hearts, etc) from the inherited "deck".

I have been having a lot of trouble with this because when I try to modify the inherited list, regardless of what I try, python will return an error, usually with 'NoneType' being the main root of the problem. Here is the code for the "even" class init:

```
def __init__(self):
    x = Deck.__init__(self)
    for card in x:
        if card.rank() == 2:
            x.pop(card)
    return x
```

It is worth noting that my card class has a method rank() which will return the rank of the card as an int.

Regardless of all the things I have tried, there is always something wrong with it. Sometimes it will say "'NoneType' object is not iterable" or "subscripable" and when I check the type() of x it is a NoneType. I have done a lot of searching around but nothing is making sense to me about NoneType or what I should do to fix it.

If I remove the for loop then the code will create a deck of 52 cards as expected, but I need to filter out the 2's for example.

Edit:
this is my deck class **init**:

```
class Deck(list):
    def __init__(self):
        return list.__init__(self, [Card(i) for i in range(52)])
```

If you cant tell, Card is also a class and the **init** of deck creates 52 card objects

Comment: ``__init__`` returns None, which leads to the error message. Can you show how the cards are stored in the base class? Alternatively, a function like ``Deck.get_even_cards`` might be more suitable instead of inheritance.

Comment: Well I NEED to have "deck" as my base class. Is this the same thing as having to inherit it? Are having something as your base class and inheritance the same thing?

Comment: @frosty: Please show the code for your `Deck` class (or at least its `__init__`).  What you should be doing is modifying attributes `self` directly, but how to do that depends on how `Deck` is storing the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So assuming a simple version of your `Deck` baseclass, inheriting an modifying the list of cards stored in the baseclass could be done something like:

```
# simple baseclass that contains a list of Card objects
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = [...] # some list of cards

# a class to hold only even cards
class Even(Deck)
    def __init__(self):
        # use super to instantiate the baseclass
        super(Even,self).__init__(self)

        # create a local instance of `deck` that contains only even cards
        # the base set of cards can still be acessed via super(Even,self).deck
        self.deck = [card for card in self.deck if card.rank() != 2]
```

EDIT: updating for the added information in the question:

```
class Deck(list):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Deck,self).__init__([Card(i) for i in range(52)])

class Even(Deck)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Even,self).__init__(self)
        [self.remove(card) for card in self if card.rank()==2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the way you're doing things in `Deck`, what you would have to do in your subclass is:

```
def __init__(self):
    Deck.__init__(self)
    self[:] = [card for card in self if card.rank() != 2]
```

Since your object inherits from `list`, it is a list, and so you can modify it by assigning directly to a slice.

However, this is probably not the best way to design your class.  Instead of inheriting from `list`, it is usually easier to store a list internally and modify it to do what you want.

Note that you should not return anything from `__init__`.  `__init__` does not return the value of the object; it is supposed to modify `self` to set whatever it wants, and always return None.  The only reason you're getting away with returning in `Deck` is that you return the value of a superclass `__init__`, which itself returns None as a good `__init__` should.